# How do I use Dartlang IOOverrides, particularly createFile?

Tags: dart

I'd like to use the Dart `IOOverrides` to run some code in a tweaked environment. Particularly, I want to take some tests which were running a Dart program as a separate executable, and run it by invoking the `main()` within the test. I need to intercept stdout and stderr, which I can do with `IOOverrides`. But I also want to make sure that it runs within a target directory, not the test directory.

So if I intercept createFile, it might be

```
File myCreateFile(String path) => File(modifyThePathAsDesired(path));
```

But I can't do that, because the File constructor is intercepted, and it stack overflows. I can work around this because the `File.fromRawPath` constructor does not need some to be affected by IOOverrides. So I can convert the path to bytes and use that, but it feels more like taking advantage of a bug than a proper solution. I do want it to return a File, and I don't have access to the SDK's _File class to create it that way. I couldn't find any examples of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious, but I think the key insight from [the `IOOverrides` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/IOOverrides-class.html) is:

> The implementations in this base class default to the actual `dart:io` implementation.

So you therefore can use the `IOOverrides` base class implementations to perform the original, unoverridden work.  If you're using [`IOOverrides.runWithOverrides`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/IOOverrides/runWithIOOverrides.html) with a class that `extends IOOverrides`, you already have access to the base class via `super`:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

String naiveModifyPath(String s) => path.join('bar', s);

class CustomIOOverrides extends IOOverrides {
  @override
  File createFile(String path) => super.createFile(naiveModifyPath(path));
}

void main() {
  IOOverrides.runWithIOOverrides(
    () {
      var f = File('foo.txt');
      print(f.path); // Prints: bar/foo.txt
    },
    CustomIOOverrides(),
  );
}
```

If you're instead using [`IOOverrides.runZoned`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/IOOverrides/runZoned.html), you can make a trivial class that extends `IOOverrides` so that you can instantiate it:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

String naiveModifyPath((String s) => path.join('bar', s);

class OriginalIO extends IOOverrides {}

final originalIO = OriginalIO();

void main() {
  IOOverrides.runZoned(() {
    var f = File('foo.txt');
    print(f.path); // Prints: bar/foo.txt
  }, createFile: (path) => originalIO.createFile(naiveModifyPath((path)));
}
```

(Note that the `naiveModifyPath` implementations above are just for demonstrative purposes; they are very naive.  For example, they probably won't do what you want if given an absolute path.)